# Sass import tags

Tags: sass

im new to sass and having some trouble with imports. These are my imports

```
@import "reset";
@import "variables";
@import "fonts";
@import "mixins";
@import "grid";
@import "foundations";
@import "forms";
```

and these are the name of my documents reset.scss, variables.scss, fonts.scss, mixins.scss, grid.scss, foundations.scss, forms.scss.

Any idea why they are not importing?

Thanks

Comment: The only reason I can think of with that information is that the SCSS files are in a different directory than this file that's importing them. If so, you would have to specify the path in the `@import`. Is that the case, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the documents inside the Main sass file must match the names of the files you are trying to import, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: I don't believe that is true ([Sass documentation makes no such claim](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import)), and I just tried an experiment and verified that I had no trouble importing SCSS files without an underscore at the front of the name.

Answer (score -1):

Something that you may want to look into is [SMACSS](http://smacss.com/) it will help you structure your document and avoid Nested craziness!

Answer (score -1):

See "Partials" here: http://sass-lang.com/guide

I see you're using Foundation, so definitely also read this regarding partials for it: http://zurb.com/university/lessons/35